# Dataset for code analysis

Tags: data-request

I am looking for a data set that contains source codes in different programming languages and it is tagged with bugs in the code.

Comment: Hi there. Is this for many pieces of code written for many computer languages? it might help if you also said what the purpose was for the data.

Comment: I have several ideas that I would like to try. I would like to experimenting with automatically suggesting code and also with forecasting potential bugs. I would prefer the dataset to be a scripting language, such as Python but MatLab and C would be good as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MUSE Open Datasets](https://www.muse-portal.net/datasets)

[Code and Comments](https://helicon-public-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/code_and_comments.tar.gz)

The code and comments dataset is a compilation of code blocks and their related comments from 106,304 different Github projects. A total of 16,115,540 code-comment pairs were obtained by running Doxygen on C, C++, C#, Java, and Python projects. One of the primary goals of this data set is to provide an association between source code and a description of that code. This allows one to perform tasks such as training a machine learning model to predict a comment for a [given snippet of code](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-Convolutional-Neural-Network-for-Source-Code-Moore-Gelman/6a8fce6c28e26342df10cad6806016f081f0f796). [5G]

[Code and Binaries](https://helicon-public-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/code_binaries.tar.gz)

The code and binaries dataset is a compilation of source code projects and their related build outputs from 3,049 different Github projects. Over 30,000 build outputs were produced from C and C++ projects. One of the primary goals of this data set is to provide an association between source code and the build artifacts of that code. This allows one to perform tasks such as binary analysis or reverse engineering. [7G]

[Code and Static Analysis](https://helicon-public-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/code_and_static_analyzer.tar.gz)

The code and static analysis dataset is a compilation of source code and their outputs from running the static analysis tool, [infer](https://fbinfer.com/), on 3,170 different C and C++ Github projects. One of the primary goals of this data set is to provide an association between source code and a static analysis of that code. This allows one to perform tasks such as predicing the static analysis output on source code. [11G]

---

[GH Archive](https://www.gharchive.org/) is a project to record the public GitHub timeline, archive it, and make it easily accessible for further analysis.

---

[GitHub on BigQuery: Analyze all the open-source code](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/github-on-bigquery-analyze-all-the-open-source-code)

---

More resources

GitHub Releases Dataset of [Six Million Open-Source Methods](https://syncedreview.com/2019/10/01/github-releases-dataset-of-six-million-open-source-methods-for-code-search-research/) for Code Search Research